# how change int to binary. on python 2.5

Tags: python

```
print 077777#how can i get binary
```

i use python2.5

Comment: are you asking how you can *print* an integer in binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest (not fastest!) way to get a binary string for an int in Python 2.5:

```
def dobin(n):
  digs = []
  s = ''
  if n<0:
    s = '-'
    n = -n
  while True:
    digs.append(str(n % 2))
    n /= 2
    if not n: break
  if s: digs.append(s)
  digs.reverse()
  return ''.join(digs)
```

Are you looking for speed, or for clarity?

Answer (score 6):

Make a map of hexadecimal characters to binary sequences, then run the number through (note: only works for non-negative numbers):

```
def bin(value):
    binmap = {'0': '0000', '1': '0001', ..., 'f': '1111'}
    return ''.join(binmap[x] for x in ('%x' % (value,))).lstrip('0') or '0'
```

Comment: I'd probably make this return `0b` prepended, for compatibility with the built-in `bin` function present in Python 2.6.

Comment: `return '-0b'[value>=0:] + ... % (abs(value),) ...` to make it support negative numbers and be compatible with [`bin`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#bin)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some recipes from ActiveState Code you might find helpful: [Format integer as binary string](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/219300/)

---

My initial answer only works in Python 2.6 and up as Alex correctly pointed out.

> Like this:
>
> `print '{0:b}'.format(077777)`

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 1234

"".join([["0", "1"][(n >> i) & 1] for i in reversed(range(n.__sizeof__()))])
```

although not sure if sizeof its correct.you could also calculate the highest bit set and only print those.

```
"".join([["0", "1"][(n>>i)&1] for i in range(log(n,2)+1)])
```