# How i can convert integer in to 'binary' in python

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby i do so

```
asd = 123
asd = '%b' % asd # => "1111011"
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993834/how-change-int-to-binary-on-python-2-5

Comment: The "duplicate" is for Python 2.5. Languages constantly evolve, don't be too eager to post "duplicate" question links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can also do string formatting, which doesn't contain `'0b'`:

```
>>> '{:b}'.format(123)            #{0:b} in python 2.6
'1111011'
```

Comment: Link: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Pretty cool! But it should be `'{0:b}'.format(123)`, and it is for python version ≥ 2.6 only.

Comment: Great, it is that i find out.

Comment: @Oliver: comment says it. `'{:b}'` is python 2.7 and 3.1 version.

Answer (score 7):

in Python >= 2.6 with [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html):

```
asd = bin(123) # => '0b1111011'
```

To remove the leading `0b` you can just take the substring `bin(123)[2:]`.

> **bin(x)**
> Convert an integer number to a binary string. The result is a valid Python expression. If `x` is not a Python int object, it has to define an `__index__()` method that returns an integer.
>
> *New in version 2.6.*

Comment: You could also remove the leading '0b' by doing bin(123).strip('0b').

Comment: @Justin, you should use `lstrip` instead of `strip` as the latter will strip any `0`s from the end of the string as well as the front (thereby changing the value).  The slice is probably a better way to go, as it will only ever remove those two characters from the string.

Comment: @tgray Yes, I agree now that I have thought about it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

bin() works, as Felix mentioned.  For completeness, you can go the other way as
well.

```
>>> int('01101100',2)
108
>>> bin(108)
'0b1101100'
>>> bin(108)[2:]
'1101100'
```